# I'm having a problem trying to load a Pytoch model: "Can't find Identity in module"

Tags: python, model, pytorch

When trying to load a pytorch model it gives the following attribute error

```
model = torch.load('../input/melanoma-model/melanoma_model_0.pth')
model = model.to(device)
model.eval()
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 arch = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b2')
> 2 model = Net(arch=arch)
> ----> 3 torch.load('../input/melanoma-model/melanoma_model_0.pth')
> 4 model = model.to(device)
> 5 model.eval()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in
> load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
> 591                     return torch.jit.load(f)
> 592                 return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
> --> 593         return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
> 594
> 595
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py in
> _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
> 771     unpickler = pickle_module.Unpickler(f, **pickle_load_args)
> 772     unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
> --> 773     result = unpickler.load()
> 774
> 775     deserialized_storage_keys = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
>
> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Identity' on <module
> 'efficientnet_pytorch.utils' from
> '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/efficientnet_pytorch/utils.py'>

Comment: what version of pytorch are you using? how did you save the model?

Comment: If possible, post the full stacktrace as well.

Comment: The version is 1.5.1
I saved the model in another notebook using torch.save(model, '../input/melanoma-model/melanoma_model_0.pth'),

Comment: full stacktrace done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a model class to load the parameters from the .pth into. And you are missing one step:

```py
model = Model()   # the model class (yours has probably another name)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('../input/melanoma-model/melanoma_model_0.pth'))
model = model.to(device)
model.eval()
```

There you go, I hope that solved your problem!

Comment: `arch = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b2')
model = Net(arch=arch) 
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('../input/melanoma-model/melanoma_model_0.pth'))
model = model.to(device)
model.eval()`   it still gives the same error